# How to use if-else on where clause

Tags: mysql, laravel-8

I'm trying to figure out how to use if-else on a where clause when lingkup equals "desa." Where clause only status = valid but when lingkup is "kecamatan" where clause status = valid and status_kecamatan = valid.

```
$results = DB::table('tb_lapak')
    ->select('tb_surat.lingkup', 'tb_lapak.*')
    ->join('tb_surat', 'tb_lapak.kode_surat', '=', 'tb_surat.kode_surat')
    ->when('lingkup' === 'desa', function ($query) {
        return $query->where('status', '=', 'valid');
    })
    ->when('lingkup' === 'kecamatan', function ($query) {
        return $query->where('status', '=', 'valid');
        return $query->where('status_kecamatan', '=', 'valid');
    });
```

here is the table

```
CREATE TABLE `tb_lapak` (
  `kode_lapak` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `kode_surat` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tanggal` char(35) NOT NULL,
  `nik` char(35) NOT NULL,
  `keterangan` text NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('proses','valid') NOT NULL,
  `status_kecamatan` enum('proses','valid') NOT NULL,
  `create_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `kode_lingkup` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

CREATE TABLE `tb_surat` (
  `kode_surat` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lingkup` enum('kecamatan','desa') NOT NULL,
  `nama_surat` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  `output` varchar(225) DEFAULT NULL,
  `aktif` enum('Y','T') NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Comment: Please don't post image for those tables structure, it's better if you run `SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name` and post that into your question so others can copy & paste to recreate them and attempt to help.

Comment: oke thanks for the suggestion

Comment: i have edited the table

Comment: Here's a fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5ea261f415713120571b31df6e435951 .. can you update it and input some sample data? Also edit the last part where it's remarked as EXPECTED OUTPUT. Once you've finished, just click 'Run' button on top and it will generate a new link. Paste that new link into your question. Thanks

Comment: it have solved with the answer below. thanks for the suggestion sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not need sample data, it is just a logical question

```sql
where (lingkup = 'desa' and status = 'valid')
   or (lingkup = 'kecamatan' and status = 'valid' and status_kecamatan = 'valid')
   or (lingkup not in ('desa', 'kecamatan'))
```

Comment: thanks very much sir. in solved my problem.